# Swift 3 how to make background image fill the entire UIView?

Tags: swift3

I've created one UIView and change the background image to it by using the following code

```
slot1_view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "drum_cut.png")!)
```

It's working fine on iphone but on ipad the background image become repeated.

How can I change its contentmode to something the fill the entire UIView?

Please help!!!!

Comment: Add an UIImageView to your view as its child, then set the image on the UIImageView instead.

Comment: so there is no option for non-repeat background image right?

Comment: Post your image. UIColor - Pattern Image is used for creating a repeating background to save on memory. But the way you want it to "fill" means you actually have an image and thus you should handle it as one (not a color)

Comment: @Pochi Thanks so much, I'll try to use the UIImage instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "RubberMat")
backgroundImage.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this code-

**Repeat:**

```
var img = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: img!)
```

**Stretched**

```
var img = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
view.layer.contents = img?.cgImage
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Swift5,  try this on a button click event. you might need to do some layout margin for the UIView

```
        myView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
        myView.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"bg.png")?.cgImage


         self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
This work fine for view background image

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 backgroundImage.image = AppImageAssets.appAssets.appBackgroundImage()
 backgroundImage.contentMode =  UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
 self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```